# Swift 4: 'distance(to:)' is unavailable

Tags: swift

This worked fine in Swift 3.2:

```
NSRange(location:myString.startIndex.distance(to: myIndex),length:myLength)
```

But in Swift 4 it gives the error in the title. What do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slicing strings has changed quite a bit in Swift 4. `NSRange` is generally not the right tool anymore, so how to fix this depends on the rest of the surrounding code. That said, the equivalent code in Swift 4 is this:

```
NSRange(location:myString.distance(from: myString.startIndex, to: myIndex),length:myLength)
```

See the [String Manifesto](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/StringManifesto.md) for how Strings are intended to work going forward. See [SE-0163](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0163-string-revision-1.md) and [SE-0180](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0180-string-index-overhaul.md) for more of the specific changes in 4.0.

Comment: Thank you kind sir.